# How to verify auth0 JWT in strapi (a headless cms)?

Tags: node.js, express, auth0, koa, strapi

I know how to verify auth0 jwt in express server. I send jwt in header as `Authorization: Bearer access_token`. However, I can't implement this in [Strapi](https://github.com/strapi/strapi)

here is the code how I verify auth0 jwt in express server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const jwt = require("express-jwt");
const jwksRsa = require("jwks-rsa");
const userReflection = require("./api/v1/user/reflection.js");

const checkJwt = jwt({
  secret: jwksRsa.koaJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: "https://random-texts.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
  }),
  audience: "http://localhost:1337",
  issuer: "https://random-texts.auth0.com/",
  algorithms: ["RS256"]
});

app.use("/api/v1/user", checkJwt, userReflection);
```

how can I verify auth0 jwt in each request in [Strapi](https://github.com/strapi/strapi) ?

Comment: Did you find the solution? The doc tells about it here https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/jwt-validation.html#write-our-own-logic

Answer (score -1):

If you want to verify your JWT in Strapi, you can use the `/users/me`.

You will have to set the Authentication Header (here is the [Auth documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/authentication.html#token-usage) )

If you receive the data - your token is correct.

Comment: I want to verify auth0 jwt not strapi's generated jwt. if I set auth headers for auth0 token the request always fails..